# Can't ping from both directions

Tags: networking, ping, windows-11

I have Windows 11 Pro on both a three-year-old Dell XPS 8960 machine (10.0.0.94) and also on a brand new CyberPowerPC machine (10.0.0.100). Both are on "WORKGROUP". Both are running Kaspersky Total Security.

10.0.0.94 can ping everything on the network, including 10.0.0.100.

10.0.0.100 can ping everything on the network EXCEPT 10.0.0.94.

I've checked Microsoft & Kaspersky sites without finding any apparent help.

Could somebody please point me to an answer to this?

Comment: Did you turn on Private Network, Network Discovery, and for good measure File and Print Sharing on both computers. Restart if you make changes.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention whether any other network connectivity between the two hosts is impaired - I'm thus assuming that it's just ping that's not working. There are a couple of possible causes for this:

- you've told one of the computers (probably 10.0.0.94) that your wifi network is "public / untrusted". See [Microsoft's help pages](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/make-a-wi-fi-network-public-or-private-in-windows-0460117d-8d3e-a7ac-f003-7a0da607448d) for how to change the "[Private Network / Public Network](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/make-a-wi-fi-network-public-or-private-in-windows-0460117d-8d3e-a7ac-f003-7a0da607448d)" setting (thank you John above for your comment). If Windows classifies a network as "public" then it will block some kinds of discovery to keep random users from probing your machine.
- incorrect netmask on one or both hosts. Run the `ipconfig` command on both hosts and make sure the netmasks for 10.0.0.xxx interface are the exact same - typically 255.255.255.0 for most home networks. If the network masks don't match then it can cause problems like this.
- extra firewall restrictions on 10.0.0.94 - temporarily turn off Windows Firewall on 10.0.0.94 (see [this link from Dell](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000135271/windows-server-how-to-properly-turn-off-the-windows-firewall-in-windows-server-2008-and-above)). If pings work normally afterwards, you'll need to investigate the Windows Firewall settings.
- something up with the Kapersky suite - temporarily turn that off too and re-test.

If you can't figure it out, consider just not worrying about it, especially if all your other networking needs are working as expected. Ping is nice for diagnostics but there's almost nothing that actually needs it for normal operations.